# Error while inserting perl variable in the mysql table on html page

Tags: html, sql, perl, interchange

Error while inserting email address in the table

```
**[perl] my $username=$CGI->{salesrep}; return $username;[/perl]@gmail.com**
```

I want to insert this value in the table.

But It gives null when executed.

```
[query type=list sql="INSERT tech4less.outofstock_sku SET name='[value name]',customer_email='[value email]', phone='[value phone]', state='[value b_state]', postalcode='[value zip]', country='[value country]', **salesperson='[perl]$username[/perl]@gmail.com**', product='[value wish_product]', item_description='[value wish_descrip]', manufacturer='[value wish_man]',  category = '[value wish_cat]', business_yn='[value option]', date = now()"]
```

[/query]

Comment: What framework are you using for this?

Comment: Interchange ..this is an HTML page

Comment: Not familiar with it, is that [this framework](http://www.icdevgroup.org/i/dev)? (Asking because the [data-interchange] tag isn't really useful here - a separate tag for that framework would be welcome.)

Comment: http://www.icdevgroup.org/interchange-doc-5.2.0/frames/ictags_87.html pls see this

Answer (score 1):

If $CGI is a CGI object then access a parammeter this way:

```
my $username=$CGI->param('salesrep');
```

Read this: http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#FETCHING-THE-VALUE-OR-VALUES-OF-A-SINGLE-NAMED-PARAMETER:

Regards

Comment: How to use this in the sql statement?

Comment: I am able to print this value on the page but having issues in inserting using sql..